# Injecting functionality into a page displayed in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a page inside of an iframe, it will be running on the same server as my application, I want to fire an event whenever a certain page appears by locating an element on the page and then add a button next to that element with some functionality.  Is that feasable?  how would I put an event on the iframe so that whenever an item with that class is created it runs my code?

Comment: same server....also the same domain?

Comment: It is possible, you would just need to listen to the iframe's load event then inspect it's contents and make your modifications.

Comment: yes, it's running in the same tomcat instance.  To be more specific I'm doing this with the drools/guvnor interface.  Trying to do it without modifying the drools war itself.

Comment: just a note... same tomcat instance doesn't necessarily mean same-domain. Same domain means same subdomain, primary domain, port, and protocol.

Comment: I think it is doable as long as the iframe page is from the same domain, using http://api.jquery.com/contents/  there are questions like this before but I cannot find the right one atm. EDIT - found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe see the one after checked. I believe you should be able to bind events using the same method

Answer (score 0):

See here [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Assuming same domain, taken from the other answer

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").removeClass("hidden");

// gets the element
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv")

// so I assume this would work
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").on(...)
```